# How to read in metadata (with tags) from a text file using Python

Tags: python, csv, metadata

The data at the start of the textfile is of this format :

```
&SRS
<MetaDataAtStart>
multiple=True
Wavelength (Angstrom)=0.97587
mode=assessment
background=True
issid=py11n2g
noisy=True
</MetaDataAtStart>
&END
Two Theta(deg)  Counts(sec^-1)
10.0    41.0
10.1    39.0
10.2    38.0
10.3    38.0
```

What method can I use to extract the metadata value of wavelenght? Would the CSV Dictionary reader work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple solution would to read the header of the file:

```
f = open("data.txt", "r")
for line in f:
    if "</MetaDataAtStart>" in line:
        print "Wavelength data was not found"
        break;
    if "Wavelength" in line:
        print line.split("=")[1]
```

**Output:**

```
0.97587
```

---

**Edit:**

```
import re
f = open("data.txt", "r")
regex = re.compile(r'Wavelength \(Angstrom\)=([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*)')
for line in f:
    result = regex.search(line)
print result.group(1)
```

**Output:**

```
0.97587
```

Comment: Hello thank you for explaining, my data is not exactly in that format, in notepad the line with the meta is the first line at the top in the following format:  &SRS<MetaDataAtStart>multiple=TrueWavelength (Angstrom)=0.97587mode=assessmentbackground=Trueissid=py11n2gnoisy=True</MetaDataAtStart>&ENDTwo Theta(deg) Counts(sec^-1)

Comment: but when I copy and paste this feel into any code editor, it automatically starts a new line for each field, will this in anyway affect the results of the method outlined above?

Comment: I was able to modify the code give by 'ton1c' to:
with open("c:\\here.dat","r") as metapart:
    for line in metapart:
      if "Wavelength" in line:
        print line.split("=")[1]
It works, but what is the [1] parameter in the last line?

Comment: I edited my answer. [1] means 1 element in array after split (everything after 1 "=" until next "=")

Comment: Hey thanks again for refining your answer, but what exactly does this line do : re.compile(r'Wavelength \(Angstrom\)=([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*)') and what is the re module you are using? thanks

Comment: It's regex. Best place to read about it is the python [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup with lxml can do this. Once you find the tag with findAll() then you can extract the data. At this point Python can easily split() on \n and again on =. Let me know if you want a code sample and I'll provide one.